# Vertex group and curve modifier

Tags: bezier-curves, vertex-groups

I've created a vertex group that I want to reshape to more or less how this curve looks in the first image looks like. I'm trying to achieve this using curve modifier. Unfortunately the middle of the vertex group is moved to the edge of the curve, as seen in the other image.

Can this be fixed? Perhaps I'm trying to use wrong tool for the job? It's only my 3rd day with Blender so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the whole vertex group and grab the x axis arrow and move it toward the other end of the curve, to the right.